# Get string between two characters

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a set of strings:

```
String 1:     1*2*3*4*45*
String 2:     1*2*3*4*500*
String 3:     1*2*3*4*5*6*300*
```

The goal is to return the following strings:

```
String 1:   45
String 2:   500
String 3:   300
```

How do I achieve this using SQL queries?

Comment: if it's always the right most characters? if so, reverse the strings, and look for the first * starting in 2nd potion, grab the string to the left of that position, replace the * to '' and then reverse the string again.  or case when string like '%*45*%' then 45 when string like '%*500*%' then 500 end etc..

Comment: Database is IO device, responsible for reading and writing data. Use "right tool for the job" - process your data on code side - most of programming languages provide effective methods for that.

Comment: Lots of duplicates, pick one:   https://www.google.com/#q=stack+overflow+sql+get+substring+between+two+characters

Answer (score 2):

Using a combination of `charindex()`, `stuff()`, `len()`, `reverse()`, and `substring()`:

```
create table t (str varchar(64));
insert into t values
 ('1*2*3*4*45*')
 ,('1*2*3*4*500*')
 ,('1*2*3*4*5*6*300*');
select 
    str
  , last_value = substring(
       str
      ,1+len(str)-charindex('*',stuff(reverse(str),1,1,''))
      ,charindex('*',stuff(reverse(str),1,1,''))-1)
from t;
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/KYP16744

returns:

```
+------------------+------------+
|       str        | last_value |
+------------------+------------+
| 1*2*3*4*45*      |         45 |
| 1*2*3*4*500*     |        500 |
| 1*2*3*4*5*6*300* |        300 |
+------------------+------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another option. Probably going to perform the same SqlZim's fine solution. Just another way to "skin the same cat".

```
with mycte(SomeVal) as
(
    select '1*2*3*4*45*' union all
    select '1*2*3*4*500*' union all
    select '1*2*3*4*5*6*300*'
)

select *
    , reverse(left(substring(reverse(SomeVal), 2, len(SomeVal)), charindex('*', substring(reverse(SomeVal), 2, len(SomeVal))) - 1))
from mycte
```