# How to extract strings between third and fourth special characters in TSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
String 1:     1*2*3*4*5*6*  
String 2:     1*2*3*40*500*6*  
String 3:     1*2*3*400*5*600*  
String 4:     1*2*3*4000*50*6000*    

The goal is to return the following strings:  

String 1:   4  
String 2:   40  
String 3:   400  
String 4:   4000
```

Comment: the goal should be not to store multiple values in a single column

Comment: @juergend I'm sorry I don't understand what you mean?

Comment: He means that you shouldn't store multiple values in one database field - it is very bad database design.

Comment: This is also a problem that is much more suitable for a solution in application code and not database code (as text manipulation in SQL isn't great).

Comment: @DigiFriend...agreed. But this is an existing design. So I can't really change anything at this point.

Comment: Existing design is not an excuse for not fixing something.  There are always alternatives.  If you can't change the existing table, make a new table, and use any of the solutions below to store your data in a usable manner.

Comment: Thanks @Andrew. I appreciate your comment

Comment: This is yet another copy of your question from yesterday that has been answered around this site dozens and dozens of times...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43721675/get-string-between-two-characters

Comment: @SeanLange no it's not. I asked the question you're referring to and I wrongly thought it was a duplicate too.

Comment: Oh I see...slightly different topic since now you need a splitter. ;)

Answer (score 4):

Just about any parse/split function will do.  This in-line approach does not require a UDF, and also returns the item sequence.

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable table (ID int,SomeCol varchar(500))
Insert Into @YourTable values
(1,'1*2*3*4*5*6*'),
(2,'1*2*3*40*500*6*'),
(3,'1*2*3*400*5*600*'),  
(4,'1*2*3*4000*50*6000*')

Select A.ID
      ,B.RetVal
 From  @YourTable A
 Cross Apply (
                Select RetSeq = Row_Number() over (Order By (Select null))
                      ,RetVal = LTrim(RTrim(B.i.value('(./text())[1]', 'varchar(max)')))
                From  (Select x = Cast('<x>' + replace((Select replace(A.SomeCol,'*','§§Split§§') as [*] For XML Path('')),'§§Split§§','</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml).query('.')) as A 
                Cross Apply x.nodes('x') AS B(i)
             ) B
 Where RetSeq=4
```

**Returns**

```
ID  RetVal
1   4
2   40
3   400
4   4000
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This was helpful!

Comment: @Solution Happy it helped

Answer (score 3):

In SQL Server 2016+ you can use `string_split()`.

In SQL Server pre-2016, using a CSV Splitter table valued function by Jeff Moden:

```
select 
    str
  , s.ItemNumber
  , s.Item
from t
  cross apply dbo.DelimitedSplit8k(t.str,'*') s
where s.ItemNumber = 4
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/HYCF1752

returns:

```
+---------------------+------------+------+
|         str         | ItemNumber | Item |
+---------------------+------------+------+
| 1*2*3*4*5*6*        |          4 |    4 |
| 1*2*3*40*500*6*     |          4 |   40 |
| 1*2*3*400*5*600*    |          4 |  400 |
| 1*2*3*4000*50*6000* |          4 | 4000 |
+---------------------+------------+------+
```

splitting strings reference:

- [Tally OH! An Improved SQL 8K “CSV Splitter” Function - Jeff Moden](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/)
- [Splitting Strings : A Follow-Up - Aaron Bertrand](https://sqlperformance.com/2012/08/t-sql-queries/splitting-strings-follow-up)
- [Split strings the right way – or the next best way - Aaron Bertrand](https://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings)
- [**`string_split()`** in SQL Server 2016 : Follow-Up #1 - Aaron Bertrand](https://sqlperformance.com/2016/04/sql-server-2016/string-split-follow-up-1)

Comment: Thanks a lot @sqlZim!

Comment: Thanks for the spell check

Comment: @JohnCappelletti Happens to me all the time too

Comment: @SqlZim You going to let this stand?  http://stackoverflow.com/users/6923888/m-sherby

Comment: @JohnCappelletti I don't know who gave Gir internet access, but they broke his grammar protocols as well.

Comment: @SqlZim  Not cool.  He didn't even change the field names  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43789578/split-one-column-value-into-multiple-column-values/43789876#43789876

Comment: @JohnCappelletti Wow. On the bright side... he probably just googled the question and found your answer to a similar question, which is nice.

Comment: @SqlZim True and flattering, but he clearly lifted the code without understanding it.  It doesn't even solve the issue.

Comment: @JohnCappelletti True, but when children are learning to talk they speak gibberish... you're seeing your code-son taking his first steps! And he does have the disclaimer "Change as needed" (which applies to all code, really)

Comment: @SqlZim OK that was funny