# Split one column value into multiple column values

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, split

I have table of subscriptions and the subscription number is actually one value stored in one column. We have the following sample values

```
SC 5-1395-174-25P 
SC 1-2134-123-ABC C1-2
SC 12-5245-1247-14&P
SC ABCD-2525-120
```

So we need to split this into individual columns. So the above four should be split the following way

```
**Col1**   **Col2**   **Col3**   **Col4**  **Col5**  **Col6**   **Col7**
**SC**      **5**     **1395**   **174**   **25P** 
**SC**      **1**     **2134**   **123**   **ABC**   **C1**      **2**
**SC**      **12**    **5245**   **1247**  **14&P**
**SC**      **ABCD**  **2525**   **120**
```

Comment: Ahhh multiple values in one column, inconsistently delimited...  Insert pointless suggestion to change schema here.

Comment: which version of SQL Server?

Answer (score 5):

Here is an in-line approach

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable table (SomeCol varchar(max))
Insert Into @YourTable values
('SC 5-1395-174-25P'),
('SC 1-2134-123-ABC C1-2'),
('SC 12-5245-1247-14&P'),
('SC ABCD-2525-120')


Select B.*
 From  @YourTable A
 Cross Apply (
                Select Pos1 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[1]','varchar(max)')))
                      ,Pos2 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[2]','varchar(max)')))
                      ,Pos3 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[3]','varchar(max)')))
                      ,Pos4 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[4]','varchar(max)')))
                      ,Pos5 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[5]','varchar(max)')))
                      ,Pos6 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[6]','varchar(max)')))
                      ,Pos7 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[7]','varchar(max)')))
                From  (Select Cast('<x>' + replace((Select replace(replace(A.SomeCol,' ','-'),'-','§§Split§§') as [*] For XML Path('')),'§§Split§§','</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml) as xDim) as A 
             ) B
```

**Returns**

[image]

> EDIT

**1) Create Your Table**

```
CREATE TABLE MyNewPubTable (PUB_FORM_NUM NVARCHAR(50) , COL1 NVARCHAR(10) , COL2 NVARCHAR(10) , COL3 NVARCHAR(10) , COL4 NVARCHAR(10) , COL5 NVARCHAR(10) , COL6 NVARCHAR(10) , COL7 NVARCHAR(10))
```

**2) Execute the Query**

```
Declare @YourTable table (PUB_FORM_NUM varchar(max))
Insert Into @YourTable values
('SC 5-1395-174-25P'),
('SC 1-2134-123-ABC C1-2'),
('SC 12-5245-1247-14&P'),
('SC ABCD-2525-120')

Insert Into MyNewPubTable
Select A.PUB_FORM_NUM
      ,B.*
 From  @YourTable A
 Cross Apply (
                Select Pos1 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[1]','varchar(max)')))
                      ,Pos2 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[2]','varchar(max)')))
                      ,Pos3 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[3]','varchar(max)')))
                      ,Pos4 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[4]','varchar(max)')))
                      ,Pos5 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[5]','varchar(max)')))
                      ,Pos6 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[6]','varchar(max)')))
                      ,Pos7 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[7]','varchar(max)')))
                From  (Select Cast('<x>' + replace((Select replace(replace(A.PUB_FORM_NUM,' ','-'),'-','§§Split§§') as [*] For XML Path('')),'§§Split§§','</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml) as xDim) as A 
             ) B
```

**3) Review the Results**

```
Select * From MyNewPubTable
```

> **Edit 2**

Or you can create the table on the fly

```
Declare @YourTable table (PUB_FORM_NUM varchar(max))
Insert Into @YourTable values
('SC 5-1395-174-25P'),
('SC 1-2134-123-ABC C1-2'),
('SC 12-5245-1247-14&P'),
('SC ABCD-2525-120')

Select A.PUB_FORM_NUM
      ,B.*
 Into  MyNewPubTable
 From  @YourTable A
 Cross Apply (
                Select Pos1 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[1]','varchar(max)')))
                      ,Pos2 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[2]','varchar(max)')))
                      ,Pos3 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[3]','varchar(max)')))
                      ,Pos4 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[4]','varchar(max)')))
                      ,Pos5 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[5]','varchar(max)')))
                      ,Pos6 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[6]','varchar(max)')))
                      ,Pos7 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[7]','varchar(max)')))
                From  (Select Cast('<x>' + replace((Select replace(replace(A.PUB_FORM_NUM,' ','-'),'-','§§Split§§') as [*] For XML Path('')),'§§Split§§','</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml) as xDim) as A 
             ) B

Select * From MyNewPubTable
```

Comment: Thank you so much John. The inline approach worked. Now could I create an actual table and store these split values so we can then work on how to sort them

Comment: @SQLUser Happy it helped.

Comment: @SQLUser To create a table Select B.* into MyNewTableName

Comment: CREATE TABLE MyNewPubTable 
(PUB_FORM_NUM NVARCHAR(50) NULL,
COL1 NVARCHAR(10) NULL,
COL2 NVARCHAR(10) NULL,
COL3 NVARCHAR(10) NULL,
COL4 NVARCHAR(10) NULL,
COL5 NVARCHAR(10) NULL,
COL6 NVARCHAR(10) NULL,
COL7 NVARCHAR(10)NULL)

Insert Into MyNewPubTable values
('SC 5-1395-174-25P',NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL),
('SC 1-2134-123-ABC C1-2',NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL),
('SC 12-5245-1247-14&P',NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL),
('SC ABCD-2525-120',NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL)

Comment: But when I try to Select B.*   INTO  MyNewPubTable..does not work

Comment: Very comprehensive step by step instructions +1

Answer (score 2):

In SQL Server 2016+ you can use `string_split()`.

In SQL Server pre-2016, using a CSV Splitter table valued function by Jeff Moden:

```
select 
    id, Col1 = [1], Col2 = [2], Col3 = [3], Col4 = [4], Col5 = [5], Col6 = [6], Col7 = [7] 
from t
  cross apply dbo.DelimitedSplit8k(replace(col,'-',' '),' ') s
  pivot (max(Item) for ItemNumber in ([1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7])) p
order by id
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/PZYAF36892

returns:

```
+----+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+
| id | Col1 | Col2 | Col3 | Col4 | Col5 | Col6 | Col7 |
+----+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+
|  1 | SC   | 5    | 1395 |  174 | 25P  | NULL | NULL |
|  2 | SC   | 1    | 2134 |  123 | ABC  | C1   | 2    |
|  3 | SC   | 12   | 5245 | 1247 | 14&P | NULL | NULL |
|  4 | SC   | ABCD | 2525 |  120 | NULL | NULL | NULL |
+----+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+
```

splitting strings reference:

- [Tally OH! An Improved SQL 8K “CSV Splitter” Function - Jeff Moden](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/)
- [Splitting Strings : A Follow-Up - Aaron Bertrand](https://sqlperformance.com/2012/08/t-sql-queries/splitting-strings-follow-up)
- [Split strings the right way – or the next best way - Aaron Bertrand](https://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings)
- [**`string_split()`** in SQL Server 2016 : Follow-Up #1 - Aaron Bertrand](https://sqlperformance.com/2016/04/sql-server-2016/string-split-follow-up-1)

Comment: Only wish string_split() returned sequence number.  Good use of pivot +1

Comment: @JohnCappelletti Ya, I don't know how they missed that when implementing it. You can do something with `row_number()` though it would be an arbitrary order. Source:   [Ordinal workaround for **`string_split()**` - Solomon Rutzky](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/Feedback/Details/2433171)

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE: included the final query**

Since the data is living in a table you can use an indexed view to split the values. WHAT?!?! Yeah, what I am about to show you is faster than DelimitedSplit8K, string_split or any CLR out there. Here's how we pull it off.

**1. Create/Populate your table and a real Tally Table (aka "numbers table")**

(*note that a "cte tally/numbers table" will NOT work for this*).

```
USE tempdb
GO

-- 1. Create/Populate your table and a real Tally Table
IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.yourView') IS NOT NULL DROP VIEW dbo.yourView;
IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.tally') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE dbo.tally;
CREATE TABLE dbo.tally
(
  N int NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT pk_tally PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED(N) ,
  CONSTRAINT uq_tally UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED(N)
);
GO
IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.yourTable') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE dbo.yourTable;
CREATE TABLE dbo.yourTable
(
  SomeId  int identity NOT NULL,
  SomeCol varchar(8000),
  CONSTRAINT pk_yourTable PRIMARY KEY (SomeId)
);
GO

INSERT dbo.tally
SELECT TOP (10000) ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 1))-1
FROM sys.all_columns a, sys.all_columns b;

INSERT dbo.YourTable VALUES
('SC 5-1395-174-25P'),
('SC 1-2134-123-ABC C1-2'),
('SC 12-5245-1247-14&P'),
('SC ABCD-2525-120');
GO
```

**2. Use the dbo.tally to create an indexed view that splits out your values**

```
CREATE VIEW dbo.yourView
WITH SCHEMABINDING AS
SELECT 
 SomeId,
 SomeCol,
 position = N+1,
 Item =
 SUBSTRING
 (
   REPLACE(REPLACE(somecol, '-', '|'), ' ', '|'),
   N+1,
   ISNULL(NULLIF(CHARINDEX('|',REPLACE(REPLACE(somecol,'-','|'),' ','|'),N+1),0)-(N+1),8000)
 )
FROM dbo.YourTable
CROSS JOIN dbo.tally
WHERE N <= LEN(SomeCol) -- Use this predicate first to ensure we get a nonclustered index seek
AND (N=0 OR SUBSTRING(REPLACE(REPLACE(somecol,'-','|'),' ','|'),N,1) = '|');
GO

CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX uq_cl_yourView ON dbo.yourView(SomeId, position);
GO
```

Let's review what we have so far:

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.yourView;
```

;

```
SomeId      SomeCol              position    item
----------- -------------------- ----------- -----
1           SC 5-1395-174-25P    1           SC
1           SC 5-1395-174-25P    4           5
1           SC 5-1395-174-25P    6           1395
1           SC 5-1395-174-25P    11          174
1           SC 5-1395-174-25P    15          25P
2           SC 1-2134-123-ABC C1 1           SC
2           SC 1-2134-123-ABC C1 4           1
2           SC 1-2134-123-ABC C1 6           2134
2           SC 1-2134-123-ABC C1 11          123
2           SC 1-2134-123-ABC C1 15          ABC
2           SC 1-2134-123-ABC C1 19          C1
2           SC 1-2134-123-ABC C1 22          2
3           SC 12-5245-1247-14&P 1           SC
3           SC 12-5245-1247-14&P 4           12
3           SC 12-5245-1247-14&P 7           5245
3           SC 12-5245-1247-14&P 12          1247
3           SC 12-5245-1247-14&P 17          14&P
4           SC ABCD-2525-120     1           SC
4           SC ABCD-2525-120     4           ABCD
4           SC ABCD-2525-120     9           2525
4           SC ABCD-2525-120     14          120
```

**3. Use the Jeff Moden's "cross tab" approach for the "pivot"**

```
 WITH getItemNumber AS
    (
      SELECT 
        SomeId,
        ItemNumber = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY SomeId ORDER BY position),
        Item 
      FROM dbo.yourView WITH (NOEXPAND)
    )
    SELECT 
      SomeId ,
      pos1 = MAX(CASE ItemNumber WHEN 1 THEN item END),
      pos2 = MAX(CASE ItemNumber WHEN 2 THEN item END),
      pos3 = MAX(CASE ItemNumber WHEN 3 THEN item END),
      pos4 = MAX(CASE ItemNumber WHEN 4 THEN item END),
      pos5 = MAX(CASE ItemNumber WHEN 5 THEN item END),
      pos6 = MAX(CASE ItemNumber WHEN 6 THEN item END), 
      pos7 = MAX(CASE ItemNumber WHEN 7 THEN item END)
    FROM getItemNumber
    GROUP BY SomeId;
```

** Results **

```
SomeId  pos1    pos2   pos3    pos4  pos5   pos6   pos7
------- ------- ------ ------- ----- ------ ------ -----
1       SC      5      1395    174   25P    NULL   NULL
2       SC      1      2134    123   ABC    C1     2
3       SC      12     5245    1247  14&P   NULL   NULL
4       SC      ABCD   2525    120   NULL   NULL   NULL
```

**4. Smile while reviewing the execution plan**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try it's

```
Declare @YourTable table (ID int,SomeCol varchar(500))
Insert Into @YourTable values
(1,'5-1395-174-25P'),
(2,'1-2134-123-ABC C1-2'),
(3,'SC 12-5245-1247-14&P'),  
(4,'SC ABCD-2525-120*')

Select A.ID
      ,B.RetVal
 From  @YourTable A
 Cross Apply (
                Select RetSeq = Row_Number() over (Order By (Select null))
                      ,RetVal = LTrim(RTrim(B.i.value('(./text())[1]', 'varchar(max)')))
                From  (Select x = Cast('<x>' + replace((Select replace(replace(A.SomeCol,' ','§§Split§§'),'-','§§Split§§') as [*] For XML Path('')),'§§Split§§','</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml).query('.')) as A 
                Cross Apply x.nodes('x') AS B(i)
             ) B
 Where RetSeq=1
```

Change as needed

Comment: Golly that looks familiar

Comment: This doesn't return the desired result!

Comment: Haha John! All the way down the the table aliasing!