# How to split dynamic variable values to individual column?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have following code that is returning a variable @colsrate with following values:

```
'[5.00],[5.00],[1.00],[35.00],[1.00],[1.00],[1.00],[1.00],[1.00],[1.00]'
```

I need to transform this individual values to individual columns. How can i do that? Thanks.

```
SELECT 
    CAST((CAST(Rate AS DECIMAL(18,2))) AS NVARCHAR(255))AS Rate 
    ,LEFT((CAST(StartDate AS NVARCHAR(255))), 11) AS StartDate
    INTO #TempTab
    FROM RepoCost.vwCurrencyRate
WHERE 
    CurrencyNameFrom = @CurrencyNameFrom
AND 
    CurrencyNameTo=@CurrencyNameTo
AND 
    DimdateId= @DimdateId

SET @colsrate =  STUFF((SELECT ','+QUOTENAME(Rate)
                    FROM #TempTab
      FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
    ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
,1,1,'')
```

Comment: Add expected Output

Comment: Expected Output : Select '[5.00]' ,'[5.00]' ,'[1.00]' ,'[35.00]' ,'[1.00]','[1.00]','[1.00]','[1.00]','[1.00]','[1.00]'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this below

```
IF OBJECT_ID('Tempdb..#Temp') IS NOT NULL
Drop table #Temp
Declare @DyValue TABLE (Value nvarchar(max))
INSERT INTO @DyValue(Value)
SELECT '[5.00],[5.00],[1.00],[35.00],[1.00],[1.00],[1.00],[1.00],[1.00],[1.00]' 

Declare @DynamicCol nvarchar(max),@Sql nvarchar(max)

SELECT * INTO #Temp FROM
(
SELECT Row_number()Over(Order by (SELECT NULL)) AS ID,Split.a.value('.', 'VARCHAR(1000)') AS Value
            FROM  (
                SELECT  CAST('<S>' + REPLACE(Value, ',', '</S><S>') + '</S>' AS XML) AS Value
                FROM @DyValue
                ) AS A
            CROSS APPLY Value.nodes('/S') AS Split(a)
            )Dt


    SELECT @DynamicCol=STUFF((SELECT ', ' + ''''+CAST( Value AS Varchar(10))+'''' From #Temp
            FOR XML PATH ('')),1,1,'')  
            SELECT @DynamicCol AS ExpectedValue

    SET @Sql ='SELECT '+@DynamicCol 
    EXECUTE @Sql
    PRINT @Sql
```

It Prints like below

```
SELECT  '[5.00]', '[5.00]', '[1.00]', '[35.00]', '[1.00]', '[1.00]', '[1.00]', '[1.00]', '[1.00]', '[1.00]'
```

Answer (score 0):

This code is not mine.  It was a solution by John Cappelletti (**[here's the original link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43789578/split-one-column-value-into-multiple-column-values/43789876#43789876)**)

But works perfectly with your need

```
Declare @YourTable table (SomeCol varchar(max))
Insert Into @YourTable values
('[5.00],[5.00],[1.00],[35.00],[1.00],[1.00],[1.00],[1.00],[1.00],[1.00]')


Select B.*
 From  @YourTable A
 Cross Apply (
                Select Pos1 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[1]','varchar(max)')))
                      ,Pos2 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[2]','varchar(max)')))
                      ,Pos3 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[3]','varchar(max)')))
                      ,Pos4 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[4]','varchar(max)')))
                      ,Pos5 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[5]','varchar(max)')))
                      ,Pos6 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[6]','varchar(max)')))
                      ,Pos7 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[7]','varchar(max)')))
                From  (Select Cast('<x>' + replace((Select replace(A.SomeCol,',','§§Split§§') as [*] For XML Path('')),'§§Split§§','</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml) as xDim) as A 
             ) B
```

Comment: Please stop posting my code without proper attribution.  https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/160071/what-to-do-when-plagiarism-is-discovered