# Data manipulation using SQL Server Substring so something else

Tags: sql-server, substring

I have a table A like this:

```
ID   Col1
----------------------
1    xyz-abcccc
2    xyz-jkasdasd
3    abcds-asks
4    asdasdasda-as
```

I want to get output like this:

```
    ID   Col1
    -------------
    1    abcccc
    2    jkasdasd
    3    asks
    4    as
```

I want get output where anything before the dash `-` is ignored.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`charindex()` would be a good place to start.   The only trick is add a `dash` within the `charindex` function as a fail-safe thus avoids throwing an error.

**Example**

```
Select ID
      ,Col1 = substring(Col1,charindex('-',col1+'-')+1,len(Col1))
 from YourTable
```

**Returns**

```
ID  Col1
1   abcccc
2   jkasdasd
3   asks
4   as
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked. What should I do if I have more than 2 " - "? –

Comment: @Duffer Take a peek at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43789578/split-one-column-value-into-multiple-column-values/43789876#43789876

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of `RIGHT` and `CHARINDEX` functions as well.

**Query**

```
select [ID],
case when [Col1] like '%-%' then right([Col1], charindex('-', reverse([Col1]), 1) - 1)
else [Col1] end as [new_col1]
from [your_table_name];
```