# String Between Two delimiters ('_')

Tags: sql-server, string, substring, charindex

I am working on splitting a string into its basic components. I have figured out the first part and is working fine;

```
SELECT(SUBSTRING(Field,0,CHARINDEX('_',Field,0))) AS POS1
```

What I am currently having a problem with is the 2nd and 3rd parts. The format of the whole string is; ***character_character_character*** (where each of these fields can have a varied amount of characters).

```
SUBSTRING(Field, CHARINDEX('-',Field)+1, CHARINDEX('_',Field, CHARINDEX('_',Field)+1 - CHARINDEX('_',Field)-1)) AS POS2
```

This is working in some instances but truncating in others. I've been staring at this for so long that I am solution blind.

Also, going to tackle the third position.

Any advice would be welcomed as to why this does work the way it should.

Comment: It is ideal to work with string split function with variable delimiter as `_` http://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/querying-microsoft-sql-server/2013/09/19/how-to-split-a-string-by-delimited-char-in-sql-server/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [T-SQL split string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10914576/t-sql-split-string)

Comment: Are you splitting by underscore or by dash? You have both "CHARINDEX('-',Field)+1" and "CHARINDEX('_',Field..." in your query

Comment: @Ven that is the worst possible way to split a string. It is horribly inefficient because loops will make that thing crawl with even half way long strings. [Here](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/) is a much better option. And if you don't like that one plenty other choices can be found [here](http://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings)

Comment: Take a peek at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43789578/split-one-column-value-into-multiple-column-values/43789876#43789876

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
SELECT Field, SUBSTRING(Field,0,CHARINDEX('_',Field,0)) AS POS1, 
SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING(Field, CHARINDEX('_',Field)+1, LEN(Field)), 0, CHARINDEX('_',SUBSTRING(Field, CHARINDEX('_',Field)+1, LEN(Field)),0)) AS POS2 ,
SUBSTRING(Field, 3 + LEN(SUBSTRING(Field,0,CHARINDEX('_',Field,0))) + LEN(SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING(Field, CHARINDEX('_',Field)+1, LEN(Field)), 0, CHARINDEX('_',SUBSTRING(Field, CHARINDEX('_',Field)+1, LEN(Field)),0))), LEN(Field))  AS POS3
FROM YOUR_TABLE
```

Comment: Close. Though it creates the same problem I was encountering. When the POS1 has only 3, it displays only 4 from POS2. So on and so forth, it's always plus 1 from POS1, even though the column (middle and end) are variable in length, using the '_' to separate them.

Comment: I have updated it and I think this one really does what you want it to do. That being said, it is an ugly solution ;)

Comment: That was it. During the "break", I did manage to find a solution for the left and right values here is the final code I have;

SELECT (SUBSTRING([field],0,CHARINDEX('_',[field],0))) AS POS1

 , SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING([field], CHARINDEX('_',[field])+1, LEN([field])), 0, CHARINDEX('_',SUBSTRING([field], CHARINDEX('_',[field])+1, LEN([field])),0)) AS POS2

, RIGHT([field],CHARINDEX('_',REVERSE([field]))-1) AS POS3

Answer (score 2):

If it's always three parts you can use a trick with `replace` and `parsename`:

```
SELECT PARSENAME(val, 3) As col1,
       PARSENAME(val, 2) As col2,
       PARSENAME(val, 1) As col3
FROM Table
CROSS APPLY
(
    SELECT REPLACE(Col, '_', '.') As val
) x
```

Answer (score 0):

I've used REVERSE before to do something similar with the path and file names.There are some examples [Here](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic422232-8-1.aspx) too.

```
DECLARE @full VARCHAR(MAX)
SET @full = 'c:\windows\system\sub-folder\somefile_file-stuff.qqq'
SELECT SUBSTRING(@full, 1, LEN(@full)-(CHARINDEX('\',REVERSE(@full))-1)) AS Path
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,
I tend to use variables to get the positions and simply the process

```
declare @field varchar(300) =  'character1_character2_character3'
declare @char1Pos int =  CHARINDEX('_',@field,0)

--select @char1Pos
declare @char2Pos int = (CHARINDEX('_',@field)+@char1Pos + 1) -1
--select @char2Pos

select  (SUBSTRING(@field,0,@char1Pos)) AS POS1,
SUBSTRING(@field, -- field
          @char1Pos+ 1,--starting position for POS2
          (@char2Pos -1) - @char1Pos) --ENDING POSITION FOR POS2
          AS POS2,
     substring(@field,-- field
                ((@char2Pos +1) ),--starting position for POS3
                len(@field) - ((@char2Pos -1) - @char1Pos))--ENDING POSITION FOR POS2
                 as POS3
```

Answer (score 0):

Final working code;

```
SELECT (SUBSTRING([field],0,CHARINDEX('_',[field],0))) AS POS1
, SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING([field], CHARINDEX('_',[field])+1, LEN([field])), 0, CHARINDEX('_',SUBSTRING([field], CHARINDEX('_',[field])+1, LEN([field])),0)) AS POS2
, RIGHT([field],CHARINDEX('_',REVERSE([field]))-1) AS POS3
FROM TableName
```

Thanks all, especially Sorix.