# How to split hierarchy in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

I have a table which contains 23,000 hierarchypaths like below mentioned in the picture.
[image]

I want split these hierarchypaths like below. How can I do this in SQL Server 2014
[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to split a comma-separated value to columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10581772/how-to-split-a-comma-separated-value-to-columns)

Comment: If you have a known or maximum number of levels, take a peek at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43789578/split-one-column-value-into-multiple-column-values/43789876#43789876

Comment: Is the amount of possible groups known?

Comment: maximum group11 / groupK