# Split a database table column value of type VARCHAR into multiple values using a delimiter?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Can you split a database table column value of type `VARCHAR` into multiple values using a delimiter?

So when fetching data I would like to split values like  `text|another|other` using pipe `|` as a delimiter.

We are using stored procedures and T-SQL, I have somewhat basic understanding of SQL, but my understanding is that using STRING_SPLIT https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15 ths should be possible.

Can anyone assist me with more details?

Comment: That's correct. STRING_SPLIT would solve this by using `SELECT value FROM STRING_SPLIT('text|another|other', '|');` but does only work with SQL Server 2016+

Comment: You shouldn't store data like that in the first place. Just because there are splitting functions doesn't mean it's a good idea. It's impossible to index such fields, which means that searching for a single value requires scanning the entire table

Comment: No split function can solve this - it's a design bug, not a coding bug. If you don't care about querying on the other hand, it's probably *better* to split the values on the client and do whatever you want with them

Comment: I am dealing with very obstinate data architecture guy, and he says flat in my face that we can't do it. Even with my limited knowledge of SQL (I am a UI dev) it sounds strange, so please don't downvote  - just help me out here.

Comment: Any *good* data architecture knows that storing delimited data in an RDBMS is a foolish idea. For starters, you have no chance of implementing foreign keys, which means you can't maintain data integrity. it's a path you don't want to go down.

Comment: The data is stored by other company - we receive it like that and our data architecture guy employs stored procedures to pass that on to the API layer and then to frontend.

Comment: @codeepic in that case clean up the data *before* loading it into your own database. It's far easier to split and handle values in code. For example, do you want separate *columns* or *rows* from those values? If rows, you'll have to *repeat* all other fields. Table rows can't be nested. When loading the data though, you can split, nest, extract the data any way you want, store it anywhere you want

Comment: @codeepic finally (again), if you don't need to filter using that data, just pull it to the client and split it there. Now, if the DBA says you can't just query such data in the database *listen to him*. You can't, not without reading and parsing every row in that table. Again, no indexing can accelerate this. If you have 100K rows, you have to split 100K values, one by one

Comment: UI Dev should consult at least senior or even junior database dev for such case scenarios

Comment: @codeepic with a properly designed table though, searchin eg for rows with `other` using an index may only need to look into 3 or 4 levels in a B-tree index. This can be 100K times faster

Comment: In the ideal word yes, but this is a very weird situation - they guy works in different office 6 hour time diff - we don't have a single database architect on site and the whole database access is gatekept by him through stored procedures. The whole team is delayed and outright blocked by his decisions sometimes and it has been raised multiple times with the management. At this point in time, I am fed up with having to resort to weird implementations in code to work around this guy.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos - can you explain a bit more more about `other` - send me some links please.

Comment: Just curious.  Were you looking to split into columns or rows?  If known or maximum number of columns, take a peek at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43789578/split-one-column-value-into-multiple-column-values/43789876#43789876

Comment: Does the order of the elements have any significance, e.g. `'ready|fire|aim'`? [`String_Split`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) says: "The output rows might be in any order. The order is not guaranteed to match the order of the substrings in the input string." There are other approaches that maintain the order, e.g. [Jeff Moden's string splitter](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/tally-oh-an-improved-sql-8k-%E2%80%9Ccsv-splitter%E2%80%9D-function).

Comment: Thanks for the explanations guys. The order doesn't matter. We will actually be filtering by tags, so I am curious how he is gonna figure it out. I could do a simple string split on the frontend, but I refuse to map db data to other types because he decided that's how he is gonna store values but also on principle and on effort required (very large data sets, updating multiple interfaces in TS, more logic, possible perf bottleneck, immutable data structures). So yeah, I know the simple answer is just do it on the frontend but that's not my point.

Answer (score 2):

It is definitely possible, and pretty straight-forward with `STRING_SPLIT`.  Even before SQL Server 2017 when `STRING_SPLIT` was introduced it was possible, just not as pretty.

An example with your string would be something like this:

```
DECLARE @t TABLE (ID INT, StringVal VARCHAR(1000));

INSERT @t
VALUES (1, 'text|another|other');

SELECT *
FROM @t
CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(StringVal, '|');
```

The results of this are

```
ID| StringVal          | value
--------------------------------
1 | text|another|other | text
1 | text|another|other | another
1 | text|another|other | other
```

So to answer your question, yes it is definitely possible.  However, you should certainly take the comment discussion into consideration.

Answer (score 2):

Well as Panagiotis Kanavos said as a comment, the best and easiest would be to this in the 'Transform' part of your ETL (Extract, Transform, Load). 
When you do this, you don't even have to deal with SQL : since you are on SQL-SERVER i assume you use SSIS. You can call an external C# or .Net script to do all the work.

To answer your question, yes SQL provides a lot of builtin function to deals with string :  you can use substr() + charindex(), or String_split or even write your own

Microsoft doc about String Functions : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-functions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is: You can do it.

The longer answer is: You shouldn't do it, because it violates the principle of [Database Normalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization#Satisfying_1NF). Anything up to NF3 is the (arguably) bare minimum, which you should stick to.

If the data enters your database from an external source, Transform it in your [ETL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extract,_transform,_load) process before it actually enters your database.

Your database should then store the data in relational form, and other transformations to fit your frontend should be done upon retrival to make it fit your consuming applications. You can read up on the [ANSI-SPARC Architecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI-SPARC_Architecture#Three-level_architecture) if you so desire.

Comment: Yes.  This is screaming for an SSIS package to load the data.

Answer (score 1):

Please check the below answer. This might help :

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE (ID int, SampleData Varchar(100))

INSERT @Table
(ID,SampleData)
VALUES
(1, 'text|another|other'),
(2, 'sample|data|again'),
(3, 'this|should|help')


 SELECT 
     A.ID AS ID,  
     Split.a.value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)') AS SampleData  
 FROM  (
        SELECT 
            ID,  
            CAST ('<M>' + REPLACE(SampleData, '|', '</M><M>') + '</M>' AS XML) AS SampleData  
        FROM  
            @Table A
         )  AS A 
    CROSS APPLY SampleData.nodes ('/M') AS Split(a)
```

The Output:-

```
ID  SampleData
1   text
1   another
1   other
2   sample
2   data
2   again
3   this
3   should
3   help
```