# How to split a single column value into multiple columns with value as column names using SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server, string

I am trying to get the values from single column in to multiple columns with value as a field name. I have seen many different questions similar to this one so tried all the options but nothing helped out yet.

For Eg.,

```
Details Field value: FirstName:John|LastName:Mike|DateOfBirth:09/09/1980|Department:IT|
```

Expected as below,

[image]

```
Create table Employee(Details varchar(200), [address] varchar(50), Status# int)

insert into Employee(Details,[address], [Date] )
values ('FirstName:John|LastName:Mike|DateOfBirth:09/09/1980|Department:IT|', '344 5th cross st, MA', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
insert into Employee(Details,[address], [Date] )
values ('FirstName:Sarah|LastName:Jones|DateOfBirth:10/09/1970|Department:Admin', '444 8th avenue, PA', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
```

My Query

```
select address,  
  left(Details,charindex('|',Details)-1) as FirstName,
  substring(Details,charindex('|',Details)+1,len(Details)) as LastName  
from 
  Employee
```

This is what I am getting for my query

[image]

Comment: The *real* solution is fix your data model.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a option provided your string layout is consistent.

**Example**

```
Select A.Address 
      ,FirstName   = Pos2
      ,LastName    = Pos4
      ,DateOfBirth = try_convert(date,Pos6)
      ,Department  = Pos8
  From Employee A
  Cross Apply (
                Select Pos1 = trim(JSON_VALUE(S,'$[0]'))  -- Could be reduced to 2,4,6 & 8
                      ,Pos2 = trim(JSON_VALUE(S,'$[1]'))
                      ,Pos3 = trim(JSON_VALUE(S,'$[2]'))
                      ,Pos4 = trim(JSON_VALUE(S,'$[3]'))
                      ,Pos5 = trim(JSON_VALUE(S,'$[4]'))
                      ,Pos6 = trim(JSON_VALUE(S,'$[5]'))
                      ,Pos7 = trim(JSON_VALUE(S,'$[6]'))
                      ,Pos8 = trim(JSON_VALUE(S,'$[7]'))
                 From  ( values ( '["'+replace(replace(replace(Details,':','|'),'"','\"'),'|','","')+'"]' ) ) A(S)
              ) B
```

**Returns**

```
Address                 FirstName   LastName    DateOfBirth   Department
344 5th cross st, MA    John        Mike        1980-09-09    IT
444 8th avenue, PA      Sarah       Jones       1970-10-09    Admin
```

**EDIT - XML Version**

```
Select A.Address 
      ,FirstName   = Pos2
      ,LastName    = Pos4
      ,DateOfBirth = try_convert(date,Pos6)
      ,Department  = Pos8
  From Employee A
  Cross Apply (
                Select Pos1 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[1]','varchar(max)')))
                      ,Pos2 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[2]','varchar(max)')))
                      ,Pos3 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[3]','varchar(max)')))
                      ,Pos4 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[4]','varchar(max)')))
                      ,Pos5 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[5]','varchar(max)')))
                      ,Pos6 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[6]','varchar(max)')))
                      ,Pos7 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[7]','varchar(max)')))
                      ,Pos8 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[8]','varchar(max)')))
                From  (Select Cast('<x>' + replace((Select replace(replace(A.Details,':','|'),'|','§§Split§§') as [*] For XML Path('')),'§§Split§§','</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml) as xDim) as A 
              ) B
```

Comment: Appreciate your help @John. Thanks much. Unfortunately i am using SSMS 2014 version, so it is throwing errors for try_convert and Json_Value build in functions.

Comment: @Uba There is an XML approach as well.   Take a peek at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43789578/split-one-column-value-into-multiple-column-values/43789876#43789876

Comment: @Uba See Edit for the XML Version

Answer (score 1):

Here's an easier way using dynamic sql and a couple of REPLACE() functions...

```
DECLARE 
    @string nvarchar(4000) = N'FirstName:John|LastName:Mike|DateOfBirth:09/09/1980|Department:IT|',
    @d_sql nvarchar(4000) = N'',
    @debug bit = 0;

SELECT @d_sql = CONCAT('SELECT [',
    REPLACE(REPLACE(TRIM('|' FROM @string), ':', '] = '''), '|', ''', ['), ''';'
    );

IF @debug = 1
BEGIN 
    PRINT(@d_sql);
END;
ELSE 
BEGIN 
    EXEC sys.sp_executesql @d_sql;
END;
```

The generated SQL ends up looking like this (@debug = 1)...

```
SELECT [FirstName] = 'John', [LastName] = 'Mike', [DateOfBirth] = '09/09/1980', [Department] = 'IT';
```

Which, in turn, produces the following results (@debug = 0)...

```
FirstName LastName DateOfBirth Department
--------- -------- ----------- ----------
John      Mike     09/09/1980  IT
```