# Split Delimited String into multiple Columns in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I want to split a string in a column that is separated by space into multiple column is SQL.

I used the query below, but I get NULL values

```
select
     PARSENAME(REPLACE(FX_RAW_DATA, '  ', '.'), 1) AS Country_Code,
     PARSENAME(REPLACE(FX_RAW_DATA, '  ', '.'), 2) AS iso_Code,
     PARSENAME(REPLACE(FX_RAW_DATA, '  ', '.'), 3) AS status,
     PARSENAME(REPLACE(FX_RAW_DATA, '  ', '.'), 5) AS date,
     PARSENAME(REPLACE(FX_RAW_DATA, '  ', '.'), 6) AS rate,
     PARSENAME(REPLACE(FX_RAW_DATA, '  ', '.'), 7) AS fx
FROM process.FX_RAW_DATA_OUT;
GO
```

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results as tabular text.

Comment: Parsename() allows for only 4 positions.   Take a peek at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64232640/how-to-split-a-single-column-value-into-multiple-columns-with-value-as-column-na/64233145#64233145

Comment: Show data examples please, but if a value you run almost any function on in SQL the results will be NULL.

Comment: Sample Data
FX_RAW_DATA
01AED                 AUD                 M              30122020           .3541000                                 11
01AED                 BRL                 M              30122020          1.4138300                                 11

Comment: Expected result     
Country_Code iso_Code status date rate fx
01AED    AUD         M    30122020 0.3541 11

Comment: No different from your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62559307/how-to-separate-a-string-between-delimiter-in-sql) that was also closed as duplicate

Answer (score 1):

You don't state what version of SQL Server you are running. If `STRING_SPLIT` is not available on your version, you can do as follows (I think you are trying to split column `FX_RAW_DATA` on table `process`). Basically, you apply the calculation of each space one after the other, then substring each:

```sql
SELECT
    Country_Code = SUBSTRING(p.FX_RAW_DATA, 1, v1.chr - 1),
    iso_Code =     SUBSTRING(p.FX_RAW_DATA, v1.chr + 1, v2.chr - v1.chr - 1),
    status =       SUBSTRING(p.FX_RAW_DATA, v2.chr + 1, v3.chr - v2.chr - 1),
    date =         SUBSTRING(p.FX_RAW_DATA, v3.chr + 1, v4.chr - v3.chr - 1),
    rate =         SUBSTRING(p.FX_RAW_DATA, v4.chr + 1, v5.chr - v4.chr - 1),
    fx =           SUBSTRING(p.FX_RAW_DATA, v5.chr + 1, LEN(p.FX_RAW_DATA))

FROM process p

CROSS APPLY (VALUES(CHARINDEX(' ', p.FX_RAW_DATA)) v1(chr)
CROSS APPLY (VALUES(CHARINDEX(' ', p.FX_RAW_DATA, v1.chr + 1)) v2(chr)
CROSS APPLY (VALUES(CHARINDEX(' ', p.FX_RAW_DATA, v2.chr + 1)) v3(chr)
CROSS APPLY (VALUES(CHARINDEX(' ', p.FX_RAW_DATA, v3.chr + 1)) v4(chr)
CROSS APPLY (VALUES(CHARINDEX(' ', p.FX_RAW_DATA, v4.chr + 1)) v5(chr);
```

The first substring always starts at 1 and ends at the first break, the last substring you can just pass the full length to get the remainder of the string.

Answer (score 0):

It's not very clear from your example sample data and expected results what your data looks like. I have made some assumptions and example below should be easy to change to match your data as required.

```
DECLARE @stringarray varchar(max), --String holding your data
        @Splitcharc char(1), --split character, space in your example
        @X xml

set @stringarray = '01AED AUD M 30122020 .3541000 11' --example data line
set     @Splitcharc = '' -- this can be changed if needed

-- We start off by formatting your string into an XML format
set @X = CONVERT(xml,' <Table> <Row> <col>' +
REPLACE(@stringarray,@Splitcharc,'</col> <col>') + '</col></Row>   </Table> ')

-- The below show how you "query" each of the "columns" returned

SELECT     
  Tbl.cl.value('col[1]','VARCHAR(20)')  country_code,
  Tbl.cl.value('col[2]','VARCHAR(20)')  ISO_code,
  Tbl.cl.value('col[3]','VARCHAR(20)')  [status],
  Tbl.cl.value('col[4]','VARCHAR(20)')  [date],
  Tbl.cl.value('col[5]','VARCHAR(20)')  rate,
  Tbl.cl.value('col[6]','VARCHAR(20)')  fx   

 FROM @X.nodes('/Table/Row') as Tbl(cl)
```